# How to detect mouse click outside the form right after clicking input field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to detect if the user click outside the form. The issue is that whenever I click first the input field then clicking outside the form, the onblur listener doesn't detect.

HTML

```
<form class="foo" tabindex="0" onClick="foo('inside')" onBlur="foo('outside')">
  <input id="myInput">
</form>
<p class="p"></p>
```

CSS

```
.foo {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.foo:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

JS

```
const p = document.querySelector('.p');

function foo(x) {
  p.innerHTML = x;
}
```

[My code here](https://codepen.io/limfao/pen/rNJOxWM)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but there seems to be some intermittent glitch with codepen. I deleted and re-typed "onblur" and it was fine but then wasn't.

It works as expected on the snippet tool here and on js fiddle (and sometimes on codepen)

```js
const p = document.querySelector('.p');

function foo(x) {
  p.innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.foo:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo" tabindex="0" onClick="foo('inside')" onBlur="foo('outside')"></div>
<p class="p"></p>
```

Comment: my bad my link is not correct, i already edit it <https://codepen.io/limfao/pen/rNJOxWM>

Answer (score 0):

You are using `onBlur` event on an form. Form doesn't have a **blur event**. It's only valid for input fields. But the `onClick` event works. It can be done in any html element.

What you want is this.

```html
<form class="foo" tabindex="0" >
  <input id="myInput" onBlur="foo('outside')" onFocus="foo('inside')" />
</form> <p class="p"></p>
```

Comment: [ Here's my better visualization](https://codepen.io/martinlex/pen/xgxpBy  "My code here")<>, If i click on the orange part and click outside the orange part, it will say outside then if i click in the input tag it will say inside but right after i click outside the orange part it does not response.